# Qt Creator 3.0.0/1 with Clang -> g++' is not recognized

Tags: qt, clang, qt-creator, qt5.2

*Win 7 32, Qt Creator 3.0 and 3.1beta tried*

I try to compile a project with Clang in Qt Creator. According to ["Qt Creator and Clang"](http://blog.qt.digia.com/blog/2011/10/19/qt-creator-and-clang/) I have set `PATH` / `LLVM_INSTALL_DIR` .

LLVM was downloaded from here. http://llvm.org/releases/download.html . Settings in Qt Creator as shown below (screenshots). When I run `qmake`, I get `'g++' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file`.

Do I miss something in the big picture? Do I need to install a special Qt version (compiled for Clang)? I have a Qt 5.2 for MSVC and Qt 5.2. for MinGw on my disk.

I have tried 3.1beta as [this reads](https://blog.qt.digia.com/blog/2014/03/04/qt-creator-3-1-beta-released/) as CLANG is supported, maybe I understand it wrong.

Compiler settings in Creator:
[image: QtCreator compiler]

Kit:
[image: QtCreator Kit]

Answer (score 2):

Clang for Win32 is not supported by the stock qmake environment. Anyway, you can follow [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14579306/3307614) to get it work. After that specify the exact spec for generating Makefile:
`qmake -spec win32-clang`.